# rewrite url from example.com?prodid=qwerty to exmaple.com/abc.php?prodid=qwerty

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect from

`http://www.example.com/PartnerLogin?authID=abcde79989#$@hk`

to

`http://www.example.com/PartnerLogin.php?authID=abcde79989#$@hk`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^PartnerLogin?authID=$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^PartnerLogin?authID=$ PartnerLogin.php?authID= [NC,L]
```

I am writing above in my .htaccess but it is not working, result I am getting is:

> The requested URL example.com/PartnerLogin not found.

Answer (score 0):

> `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^PartnerLogin?authID=$ [NC]`
>   `RewriteRule ^PartnerLogin?authID=$ PartnerLogin.php?authID= [NC,L]`

`PartnerLogin` is not part of the `QUERY_STRING` and `authID` is not part of the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` pattern. Also the query string does not end (`$`) after `authId=`.

Try something like the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^authID=
RewriteRule ^PartnerLogin$ PartnerLogin.php [L]
```

The query string (ie. `authID=abcde79989`) is automatically copied across to the substitution URL. I've also removed the `NC` flags. Unless you specifically *need* a case-insensitive match, these are not required.